# Populate listbox using for loop of year starting with 1913 and ending with 2013

Tags: c#, for-loop, listbox

I cannot get a listbox of years 1913-2013 using a for loop to work. This is the code I have so far..

```
        lstYear.Items.Clear();

        int[] year;
        year = new int[100];

        for (int y = 100; y > 1913; y++)
        {
           year[y] = y + 1;
           lstYear.Items.Add(year[y]);
        }
```

Comment: `int y = 100; y > 1913; y++` sure about those numbers?

Comment: forget `for` loop. Use `Enumerable.Range()`

Answer (score 5):

to add a list of `DateTime` objects from 1/1/1913 to 1/1/2013:

```
 lstYear.Items.AddRange(Enumerable.Range(1913,101)
                                  .Select(x => new DateTime(x,1,1)));
```

to add a list of `int`s from 1913 to 2013:

```
 lstYear.Items.AddRange(Enumerable.Range(1913,101));
```

Comment: The second argument to `Range` is not the ending bounds, but rather the number of items to yield.  It should be 100 in both cases.

Comment: @Servy hahaha.. I never used starting from non-zero.

Comment: @Servy Wait, then shouldn't it be 101? I mean... if it was 1, it would return just 1913. if it was 11, it would return 1913-1923. He wants 1913-2013, so... 101.

Answer (score 1):

This loop:

```
for (int y = 100; y > 1913; y++)
{
   year[y] = y + 1;
   lstYear.Items.Add(year[y]);
}
```

Will never actually execute, since 100 is not greater than 1913.  In a `for` loop, the loop will continue until the expression in the middle evaluates to *false*.  You probably want:

```
for (int y = 0; y < 100; y++)
{
   year[y] = y + 1913; // Start at 1913
   lstYear.Items.Add(year[y]);
}
```

Also, I must ask, is there a *need* for the array at all?  Why not just add the numbers directly into `lstYear.Items`?  I'd probably write this as:

```
for (int y = 1913; y < 2014; y++)
{
   lstYear.Items.Add(y.ToString()); // Not sure if .ToString is needed, but I think .Add() takes a string
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are new here is the structure you want. 
You can also do it using a range, but that's out of question.

This question is how to populate using a "For" loop.

In your for loop you are starting at 100

```
for (int y = 1913; y <= 2013; y++)
   lstYear.Items.Add(y);
```